# Extract all png file and bitmap data from swf using as3

Tags: actionscript-3, png, flash

Is there any way to get a list of bitmap resource (eg png file) using as3? I know that I can go through the all child of the swf and check if each child is a shape or not, if yes, then I can get back the bitmap data by

var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(obj.width, obj.height, true, 0);
bmd.draw(obj);

and then write out the bmd as a png file. However, by doing this I cannot know which png resource this object associate with, also if the object instance is inside an animation, this approach may not successfully capture the bitmap data correctly. Any better idea?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can play with these libraries [as3swf](https://github.com/claus/as3swf) (as3swf is a low level Actionscript 3 library to parse, create, modify and publish SWF files.) and [Velocity 9 SWF Inspector](https://github.com/velocity9/Inspector) (A handy little tool to peek inside SWF files)